# Getting Cucumber cannot resolved type

Tags: cucumber-java

While using `@RunWith(Cucumber.class)` I am getting:

`Cucumber cannot be resolved to type and class <Cucumber>cannot resolved to a type.`

But no any suggestions to import library statement.
If I import it manually by using `import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions` then getting `Cucumber.api` cannot resolved to the type.
Is there any dependency or any external jars that needed to be added?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added Cucumber as a dependency to your project? You can do so with Maven or Gradle. 
For instance, if you are using Maven, you need to add the following dependency to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Note that 3.0.2 is the current version atm. There will be new versions released. You can find the latest version either in the documentation or on [GitHub](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm).

You can find more information about installation here: https://docs.cucumber.io/installation/java/